# What books to read for MCMC theory?

Tags: references, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process

Suppose one is interested in stochastic processes for the purpose getting a theoretical understanding of MCMC. They already have a decent understanding of probability theory (let's say at the level Billingsley) and want to develop enough tools to potentially prove theorems about the Markov Chains they construct at a research level.

What book or sequence of books would be reasonable for getting up to speed on the theory?

EDIT: This is not a question about applying MCMC. It is essentially asking for a mathematics textbook. Something less like Robert and Casella and more like Meyn and Tweedie (an answer I probably would have accepted when I asked this question).

Comment: There's been some other discussions on similar topics -- see e.g. [Textbook deriving Metropolis-Hastings and Gibbs Sampling](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/textbook-deriving-metropolis-hastings-and-gibbs-sampling)

Comment: @StasK sure, but I don't know that question was aimed at doing research on MCMC theory. I mean, at the very least, an adequate answer to *this* question would feature a resource for a rigorous, measure theoretic, treatment of stochastic processes.

Comment: My feeling is that this is a very, very long shot in the current practice of MCMC. I would too question measurability of the processes with infinitely many parameters, as counterexamples can be constructed with some wit. At best, you can hope to see an introduction to Markov chain theory, as in Gilks, Richardson and Spiegelhalter (1996). May be there are more modern theoretical books -- I am not a Bayesian, and don't aim to be one, although I have half a dozen books on my shelf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good sources for learning Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5885/good-sources-for-learning-markov-chain-monte-carlo-mcmc)

Comment: @Tim I disagree. Both the links ask the question of good books for MCMC sampling methods and theoretical understanding of MCMC methods. This question asks for books to understand the stochastic processes used in MCMC. The books in my answer (except for Brooks et al.) really don't talk about MCMC, but just general state space Markov chains. Which is I think what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Greenparker IMHO those two threads are closely related and it would be better to link them by marking as duplicates. Btw, thanks for your nice answer (+1).

Comment: @Tim This is not a duplicate, as hinted at from my previous reply to StasK. When I asked this question (almost 4 years ago!) it was because I did not find the treatment of Robert and Casella rigorous enough. None of the texts, I think, in the post you linked to would have been adequate answers to this question.

Comment: @Greenparker I was planning to, but since this question has generated more interest in the last day I thought I would wait to see if it generated any more answers. Marking as correct will stop others from answering. I'll accept an answer in probably the next day or so.

Comment: @guy I'm not insisting on that. What I'm saying is only that marking this as a duplicate would make it easier for people to find the two questions about MCMC references. The topic is narrow enough that the questions could be considered as *similar*. It would also make the page better organized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are asking for MCMC theory, I am assuming Markov chains on general state space is of the most interest here. Here I provide some books/articles and what they are good for.

1. [Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability](http://probability.ca/MT/) by Meyn and Tweedie. This is considered to be the most thorough book on the theory for Markov chains in MCMC. You will find that most research in the theory of MCMC refer to this book often. Their treatment is fairly measure theoretic, too much maybe for my taste. This is probably a good one stop place.
2. [General Irreducible Markov Chains and Non-Negative Operators](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052160494X) by Nummelin. This is a thin and (very) concise book on general state space Markov chains. To be honest, it takes a lot of time to wrap your head around the notation. Not my favorite, but rigorous nonetheless.
3. [General State Space Markov Chains](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ps/1099928648) by Roberts and Rosenthal. This is not a book, but a survey paper on MCMC methods with detailed theory. This would be the *perfect* place to start for someone interested in MCMC theory. They also cite various books for readers to refer to.
4. [Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420079417) by Brooks, Gelman, Jones, and Meng. Not theoretical but definitely more recent (and in my view better) than other MCMC practice books.

Comment: +1 for citing the Brooks et al. book, definitely the best for MCMC users. I'm curious to know why you didn't include [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods](https://www.amazon.com/Monte-Statistical-Methods-Springer-Statistics/dp/1441919392) by Robert and Casella - it's fairly theoretical and I think including it would make the answer more complete. Or do you have specific reasons for not recommending it?

Comment: @DeltaIV I only included the Handbook as the one on the practice of MCMC and because I really like the book. I didn't include Robert + Casella because the OP in the comments had said that [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/textbook-deriving-metropolis-hastings-and-gibbs-sampling) does not have the answer to their question. The OP want's a book they can use to study the behavior of MCMC Markov chains, for which I personally don't think R+C is a good book.